# How to save Oracle connection string to variable in Java

Tags: java, oracle, database-connection, connection-string

Can I use a variable in the DriverManager.getConnection parameter to make it dynamic.

```
    String connstring = null;       
    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection                 
               ("jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:port:sid","uname","pword");                             
               //(connstring);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

However, when I tried to encapsulate the connection string to a variable like the code below. I am getting an "Invalid arguments in call".

```
    String connstring = null;       
    connstring = "\"jdbc:oracle:thin:" + host + ":" + port + ":" + sid + "\"" + "," + "\"" + uname + "\"" + "," + "\"" + pword + "\"";
    System.out.println(connstring);
    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connstring);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I print out the variable and it is exactly the same with the first approach quotes and all.

I also tried a different approach like the one below. This time I am getting a "Invalid Oracle URL specified".

```
    Connection con = null;

    try {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbaseurl, dbaseuser, dbasepwrd);
        //con.setAutoCommit(false);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Oracle JDBC Driver Missing");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Connection could not be obtained.");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
```

I've researched the oracle url for 10g and it seems in order. Below is how I initialized the dbaseurl variable.  The goal is not to hard code the connection properties. Please help. Thanks.

"jdbc:oracle:thin@hostname:port"

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have made a string out of your former code, including the `"` and `,` characters.

Comment: Ok. Based from this, placing the connection string in a variable and then calling it from the get connection is not viable. However, I also tried this approach but still not working

Comment: conn = DriverManager.getConnection
       ("\"jdbc:oracle:thin:\"" + host + ":" + port + ":" + sid + "\"" + ",\"" + uname + "\"," + "\"" + pword + "\"");

Comment: If you set those values to a,b,c..., the value of that string is: `"jdbc:oracle:thin:"a:b:c","d","e"`. ie, it has the `"` and `,` characters in it. These shouldn't be in your connection string.

Answer (score 0):

Probably just need some hints. But this worked. Instead of one string. I saved each argument to a variable.

```
    String dburl = "jdbc:oracle:thin:" + host + ":" + port + ":" + sid;
    System.out.println(dburl);

    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection
               //("\"jdbc:oracle:thin:\"" + host + ":" + port + ":" + sid + "\"" + ",\"" + uname + "\"," + "\"" + pword + "\"");

                (dburl,uname,pword);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```